# Get result from php in android studio using simple runnable threads without any external libraries

Tags: java, php, android, sql-server

So, I know this might seems like a repeated question, but bear with me for a moment. In Android Studio, instead of using any external libraries (i.e., no JSON, no Volley, no Retrofit, nothing external), I plan to use simple runnable threads. These will fetch data using PHP stored on the localhost through the IP address of the WiFi which my system is using.

I know how to send a PHP update (the actual update codes are in PHP script), it's done like this:

```
Runnable runnableToUpdateDb = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("DEBUG","RUNNING RUNNABLE");
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.43.242/myapi/php_name.php");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            String response = bufferedReader.readLine();
            Log.d("DEBUG", response);
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
         }catch (Exception e){
             Log.d("DEBUG",e.toString());
         }
    }
};
```

And then simply running the PHP using thread upon the press of the button by:

```
Thread threadToUpdateDb = new Thread(runnableToUpdateDb);
threadToUpdateDb.start();
```

Now, the problem is in setting up a TextView that shows the updated/new data from the database though a different PHP.

The id I've described for this TextView in the layout is:

```
android:id="@+id/getdata"
```

I need help for implementing it in MainActivity.

The output for PHP is in the form of:

```
<br>8<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you perform a HTTP GET to an URL using plain Android. In this case I choose an AsyncTask so it would run the request aside from the Main Thread:

```
private class TareaGetFromDB extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String URL = params[0];
        String response = null;

        try {
            // Create an HTTP client
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet post = new HttpGet(URL);
            // Perform the request and check the status code
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                // code 200 equals HTTP OK
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                try {
                    response = IOUtils.toString(content, "utf-8");

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // TODO handle exception
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            // TODO handle exception
        }
        return response;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        myTextView.setText(response);
    }
}
```

This AsyncTask takes a String (the URL) as argument and returns a String (the response).

So you'll need to call it like this:

```
new TareaGetFromDB().execute("http://url.to/get/data");
```

You may need additional work before setting the text to the TextView to remove the surronding `<br>`, or you can remove them from the server response

Comment: You're welcome! If it solves your question, would you mind accepting the answer? thanks!